# Modeling Product Inventory Variants E-Commerice with Images PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, e-commerce

There are many different answers to satisfy different online store needs.

A lot of the example I see don’t take into consideration **inventory and images ** and treat styles and sizes as attribute like tags and try to be flexible. This seems wrong to me. My Product that hasMany styles/color that hasMany Sizes.

Here is how i want to layout it out

```
Product
id | name  |  price
1  |  shirt  | 10.00

^ Styles                        <      Images
id product_id name                      id       styles_id    filename
1   1          red                      1             1       image.jpg
2   1          blue

^ Size
id sku styles_id name inventory
1   n1     1         m    50
2   n2     1         l    50
```

I don’t see many examples of this but this is what makes sense most to me. Am i totally wrong and bad to do it this way? With styles having its own table I can use a FK with images to load different looks of each style

I know one flaw is that what if I have a product that has only one style and one size. Like a winter coat. Then I to use extra tables. Visually with PHP I will just make it all one form. Will I run into an issue when i start working on cart and orders?

Note: I am using CakePHP

Response to the parent child method

Yes I have seen that before, Wouldn't you  have repeated fields or empty fields, for example your table would look like this

```
  id   role     color   size  inventory price  name
  1     parent   -        -        -     -     artShirt
  2     child    red      m       20    50.00     -
  3     child    red      l       20    50.00       -
  4     child    blue      s       20    50.00      -
  5     child    blue      m       20    50.00      -
```

how would you link img to products that are red?

```
id    product_id   image
1        2          redImg.jpg
1        3          redImg.jpg
```

Comment: If this setup is a good idea depends largely on the data you want to represent :-) It looks ok to me on first view. One question: do al your products have similar styles: red, blue, etc? If that is the case you could move these to their own table so you wont have 'red' a thousand times in your database (this is called normalization, and you'd have one table more than you now have).

Comment: Thanks, yea i thought about separate out the style name i was worried of having to many tables. I am already on 4 tables to show 1 product. Does it matter to sql? I just wanted to get some confirmation from someone. I'm a self taught developer. And there seems to be so many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

the concept i really like is called Parent Product - Child Products.
The Parent Product is given a sku for reference, but its not a buyable product. It represents the product, like the ArtSir Shirt. It contains a product description for ArtSir Shirt, qualities, keywords, etc.

the Child Products are the actual buyable products. the shirts. there is one record per child product with the sku, color, size, price, weight, inventory, etc. they are related to the Parent product by the parent product sku. for most merchants inventory is critical so having a db record per sku is really the only practical way to do this. (not to mention if you need distinct UPC or EAN codes)

the parent products and the child products can all be in - one simple happy db table. like a family :-) You call the parent product with its sku, then get the child products with the parent product sku.

and then when you get the child products, you have the option to filter out the ones with no inventory and not show them.

Showing product pictures on a product page for specific colors -- so this has nothing to do with the products being buyable or not. this is the presentation. the simplest (hack) is to put that information in the Parent product record. fields for Color 1, photo link, Color 2, photo link, etc

Otherwise you could have a separate db table to do this. Just try and confine its tasks to the presentation.

Always pass a product id to the cart - then the cart looks up the product price in the product table. If you pass the product price openly, then it can be easily hacked. When you look up the price you can also confirm inventory.

Suggest that there be one step before billing - where you check price and inventory again to confirm everything is correct before charging the customer.

==============

**edit in response to question**. you asked:
*"Wouldn't you have repeated fields or empty fields, for example your table would look like this"*

yes you will have empty fields. in 1985 or 1995 that was important. its not important any longer unless you are running your web site on a machine from that era.

bottom line you have to be able look up a sku and get the price and inventory. you could put arrays or data structures into a field. 
but then you are having to pack and unpack them every single time you make a db call.

*how would you link img to products that are red?*

you can hack it by creating fields for the parent product to hold the image links, a color reference, a name, etc. color01, photolink01,color02, photolink02, etc. its a hack but it will work.

remember you are pulling all the page display information from the parent product. so this is just more display data.

you also have the option of having a photo field in the child product record. which you might need for product feeds. so then you could take the color - photo results from the child products, and use that to create the display.

otherwise make a db table for the display. and that table could also help with uploading the product photos and assigning them to the correct product.

Comment: hi - responded above.